# How to secure wcf rest services based on OAuth

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, oauth

I need to secure wcf services based on OAuth. In this case Java application is passing me a token which i need to validate based on Oauth in .Net layer and if token is passed then need to call wcf services.

I have checked several examples based on OAuth but not got any idea to achieve this . Please help me how to achieve this based on OAuth in .net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i solved this by below implementation

```
var authHeader = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers.GetValues("Authorization");
                if (authHeader == null || authHeader.Length == 0)
                {
                    throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                }
                NameValueCollection outgoingQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);

                var parts = authHeader[0].Split(' ');
                if (parts[0] == "Bearer")
                {
                    string token = parts[1];

                    outgoingQueryString.Add("token", token);
                    byte[] postdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(outgoingQueryString.ToString());

                    var result = string.Empty;
                    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(oauthConfiguration.Setting.CheckUrl);
                    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", GetAuthorizationHeader(oauthConfiguration.Setting.ClientId, oauthConfiguration.Setting.ClientSecret));
                    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = postdata.Length;
                    using (Stream postStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        postStream.Write(postdata, 0, postdata.Length);
                        postStream.Flush();
                        postStream.Close();
                    }

                    var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```